# Schedule a repeating alarm clock

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I'm trying to schedule a repeating alarm clock for a specific time (repeating weekly). The closest thing I've got is:

Getting the exact time:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmHour);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmMinute);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, dateDelta);

long time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

And then setting the alarm (where my question comes):

```
val clockInfo = AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(time, homePI)
alarmManager.setAlarmClock(clockInfo, alarmTriggerPI)
```

The problem is that to make it repeat, I'll need to manually trigger this code again.

If I use `setRepeating` instead of `setAlarmClock` then I lose the alarm notification (for newer phones).
Again the idea is just to start a normal alarm clock that if set to go off on a Friday, it will go off on every Friday.

Comment: "The problem is that to make it repeat, I'll need to manually trigger this code again." – Yeah, it's been like that for a while – since KitKat, I believe – for any type of exact alarm. That's just how it is, unfortunately.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations on how to do it? I'm thinking to reset it (reschedule it for the next week) when the alarm goes off. @MikeM.

Comment: Yep, exactly. Just set it again when it fires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike's comment is the right answer. In short, you have to manually trigger it.